# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изменялся цвет блока div?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть HTML-код:

```
<div class="block">
          <form method="post">
          <p>Имя:</p>
          <p>Курс:</p>
          <p>Город:</p>
          <input type="button" name="grey" value="red" id="red">
          <input type="button" name="red" value="blue" id="blue">
          </form>
          </div>

<style>
.block {
            backgroung: red;
            width: 600px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

.block p {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
</style>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы блок `<div class="block">` менял свой цвет при нажатии на кнопку `<input type="button" name="grey" value="red" id="red">` либо `<input type="button" name="red" value="blue" id="blue">`.

Для этого я написал код на JS:

```
const div = document.querySelector('.block');
const btnRed = document.querySelector('#red');
const btnBlue = document.querySelector('#blue');
    
btnRed.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
})

btnBlue.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
})
```

и он работает, но только для первого блока div. Как это исправить? Я новичек во фронтэнде и реально не знаю, что можно сделать. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.color').forEach(
  b => b.addEventListener('click', 
    () => b.closest('.block').style.backgroundColor = b.value)
);
```

```css
.block {
  /*backgroung: red;*/
  width: 600px;
  /*height: 200px;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <form method="post">
    <p>Имя:</p>
    <p>Курс:</p>
    <p>Город:</p>
    <input type="button" value="red" class="color">
    <input type="button" value="blue" class="color">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <form method="post">
    <p>Имя:</p>
    <p>Курс:</p>
    <p>Город:</p>
    <input type="button" value="red" class="color">
    <input type="button" value="blue" class="color ">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Arkadiy Пожалуйста. Успехов.